# List user input of a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

How do i take a user input this way in Python ->

```
[('a',23), ('b', 37), ('c', 11), ('d', 29)]
```

I tried using this

```
tup = [] 
line = input("\n") 
while(line != ''): 
    tup.append(tuple(line.split())) 
    line = input()
print(tup)
```

This gives output as

```
[('a','1'),('b','2')]
```

which is not helpful

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the input. You don't need a loop if the user is typing `[...]`.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that output from the input you show. That's the output you'd get if you entered `a 1` and `b 2`, not the input you show at the top.

Comment: What are you actually entering in response to the input requests?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the second element of the tuple from a string to an integer?

Comment: Thats (the first code block) their expected output, poorly phrased. They need to convert the second input to int is all

Comment: What exactly is the user entering and what is the output you seek?  It looks like the user is entering two values per "line" and that your main issue is how to get the second space separated value per line cast to an integer. Is that correct?

Comment: "which is not helpful" *what exactly is the problem*?

Answer (score 2):

Assign the result of `split()` to variables so you can convert the second value to an integer when putting it into the tuple.

```
tup = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == '':
        break
    s, n = line.split()
    tup.append((s, int(n)))

print(tup)
```